# How do I center an iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, centering

I've been trying to center a couple of iframes on this page [link](http://www.americotrapeze.com/the-trapeze-difference/). However, every example I have seen I've tried and doesn't work. You can clearly see the parallax floating div that isn't centered and at the bottom the iframe for an html page is floating to the right and not centering as well.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: display:block + margin:auto; ..... did you search a bit ? :)

Comment: I searched for about 2 hours, so yes :) I did try that before. It doesn't work for whatever reason.

Comment: Again, Oriol, I have tried that. That would obviously be the first thing I would try. I wouldn't be asking if that worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/zqLdJy
change the css padding-top and bottom to suit your needs

```css
/* Flexible iFrame */

.Flexible-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.Flexible-container iframe,
.Flexible-container object,
.Flexible-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="flexible-container">
  <object width="100%" data=""https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxrMaW3xINrsR3h2cWx0OUlwRms/preview"&amp;toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0" type="application/pdf">
      <embed width="100%" type="application/pdf" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxrMaW3xINrsR3h2cWx0OUlwRms/preview"?scrollbar=0&amp;toolbar=0&amp;navpanes=0">
    </object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

`display:block` + `margin:auto;`

```css
iframe {
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
```